# 指定のフィールドに特定の文字列を含むデータを取り除くメソッドを実装したい

Tags: java

データベースの全レコードを格納したListから
「指定のフィールドに特定の文字列を含むデータ」を取り除くメソッドを
実装したいのですが、どのように記述すればよろしいでしょうか。
自分で下記のように記述してみたのですが、500エラーとなりました。恐れ入りますがご教示ください。
※データベースについてはJPAを利用してDTOを実装しています。

---

```
import Sample;　//その他必要なクラスをimport済

//--メインメソッド内--
List<Sample> samples　//へデータベースの全レコードを格納済
String keyword　//へ特定の文字列を格納済

samples = keyList(samples, keyword);

//--メインメソッドのブロック外に目的のメソッドを記述--
public List<Sample> keyList(List<Sample> list, String keyword) {
    List<Sample> newList = list;
    for(Sample sample : list) {
        if (sample.指定のgetter().contains(keyword)) {
            newList.remove(sample);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

発生している例外は[`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)ではないかと想像します。
この例外は、質問文中コードで言うと

```
for(Sample sample : list) {
        ...
            newList.remove(sample);
    }
}
```

のように、リストを`for`ループで順繰りに処理している最中(反復処理中)にリストの要素を減らしたり増やしたりすると発生します。

```
List<Sample> newList = list;
```

でなく、

```
List<Sample> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

とすれば、`list`と`newList`で異なるリストを参照することになるので前述「反復処理中の要素増減」は回避できます(ループさせているリストと要素を減らしているリストは別物なので)。

ただ、反復処理を行うには通常[`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)を用います。

Java8以降であれば[`Collection#removeIf`メソッド](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)が利用できます:

```
List<Sample> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
newList.removeIf(sample -> sample.指定のgetter().contains(keyword));
return newList;
```

古典的な書き方であれば、

```
List<Sample> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
Iterator<Sample> ite = newList.iterator();
while (ite.hasNext()) {
    Sample sample = ite.next();
    if (sample.指定のgetter().contains(keyword)) {
        ite.remove();
    }
}
return newList;
```

となります。

Comment: ご教示いただきましたIteratorを使って記述してみましたが、
Iterator<String> ite = newList.iterator();の行で「型の不一致: Iterator<Sample> から Iterator<String> には変換できません」、
Sample sample = ite.next();の行で「型の不一致: String から Sample には変換できません」と警告が出てしまいました。

    public List<Sample> keyList(List<Sample> list, String keyword) {
        List<Sample> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
　　Iterator<String> ite = newList.iterator();
　　while (ite.hasNext()) {
    　　Sample sample = ite.next();
    　　if (sample.指定のgetter().contains(keyword)) {
        　　ite.remove();
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }

Comment: 本文中のコードを修正しました。また、本文に記載した例外が原因ではない場合、質問文にある「500エラー」では情報が不足していますので、例外スタックトレースを質問文に追記してください。

Comment: なおCollection#removeIfメソッドを利用した記述は正常に動作しました。

Answer (score 0):

メソッドなかで、渡されたリスト中のエレメントを弄ったら、不具合につながる可能性があるので、変更しないほうが安全です。

```
public List<Sample> keyList(List<Sample> list, String keyword) {
    List<Sample> newList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for(Sample sample : list) {
        if (sample.指定のgetter().contains(keyword)) {
            newList.add(sample);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```